# App running in background is restarting instead of resuming when relaunching my app icon

Tags: java, android

**Please Help! I am new to android development.I am working on an app where its restarting when i relaunch my app icon,basically it should resume as my app is running in background.**
And when i am using home button and then selecting my app from recent launch its resuming perfectly.

I went through this link also but am not getting the perfect answer or perfect solution how to solve this issue.
      https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.singh"
   android:versionCode="20160114"
    android:versionName="20160114" >

    <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="18"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
     <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true"     android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@string/google_play_services_version" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.singh.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register_activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InsoleConnection"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_configuration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activities"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HistoryActivity_web"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_history"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/faceBookAppID" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivitySummery"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_summery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TreadMillActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_summery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ReportProblem"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_summery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

     <service
        android:name="************************"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <service android:name="******************************" />

</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest please?

Comment: seems like you need to add Override function `protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }`

Comment: If you are calling 'finish()' method , dont call `finish();` in `onPause()` and `onStop()` method

Comment: Could you describe your issue in more details? At least show your manifest and code of the problem activity.

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev i hv posted my manifest file.

Comment: Can you now post your Main Activity, including stuff like onPause, onDestroy and anything else that dictates the android life cycle